# Real time server monitoring

Tags: energy, server

First of all, I hope I am posting my question on the right place. I am looking forward to any possible advice.

I am using a Dell server (model: PowerEdgeR710) and I saw that on the LCD panel the current power consumption is being displayed. I am trying to find a way to real-time extract the values. Further, the logging method using IPMI tool and IDRAC is not solving my problem, since it is not real time, but instead it is returning averages of at least 5 minutes. And I am aiming for an interval of possibly 1 sec, which corresponds to what the LCD panel is displaying.

Is there a way I could do that easily? Are there any options to send a query for the value? Unfortunately, my google search did not lead to a solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried snmp? See https://mobile.twitter.com/dellcarespro/status/963142667252260864 and try oid amperageProbeReading

Comment: What did Dell say? They've got good online support .

Comment: Don’t know if Dell has something similar, but HP has the ability to read out the power consumption via a Windows or Linux program.

Answer (score 1):

You could tap into the signal that sends the values to the display, measure the consumption yourself with another circuit or read the panel with a camera.

With this much information I would go with with the camera solution, as that is easy to install to a new device. One option would be to have a camera connected to a raspberry pi and raspberry running a software using OpenCV-library for the reading. Then Rasberry could be used to interface as fits; PostgreSQL database, REST API, push through Ethernet or Serial communication.